# BeagleBone Black: Pinmuxing does not change by using Device Tree Overlay

Tags: beagleboneblack, device-tree

I am trying to change my pinmuxing modes by device tree overlays, but it seems that it has no effect to the specific registers. I tried the following tutorial:

http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/beaglebone-black/step04-gpio/

Default situation:

I am using Debian Linux, image date: 2016-01-24
kernel version: 4.1.15-ti-rt-r43

```
# output filtered for desired pins:
cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/Pins
pin 84 (44e10950.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
pin 85 (44e10954.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
pin 86 (44e10958.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
pin 87 (44e1095c.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
```

As you can see the all have mode 7, I need mode 0 (SPI0).

And no one else is using the pin (pretty much the same on every pin => GPIO UNCLAIMED):

`pin 84 (44e10950.0): ocp:P9_22_pinmux (GPIO UNCLAIMED) function pinmux_P9_22_default_pin group pinmux_P9_22_default_pin`

```
cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
 0: PF----  -1
 1: PF----  -1
 2: PF----  -1
 3: PF----  -1
 4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,cape-universaln
```

Here is my device tree:

```
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    compatible = "ti,beaglebone", "ti,beaglebone-black";

    part-number = "SPI_SLAVE_PINMUX";
    version = "00A0";

    fragment@0 {
        target = <&am33xx_pinmux>;
        __overlay__ {
            spi_slave: pinmux_spi_slave {
                pinctrl-single,pins = <
                            0x150 0x30  // SPI0_CS0  Mode 0, SPI
                            0x154 0x30  // SPI0_D1   Mode 0, SPI
                            0x158 0x10  // SPI0_D0   Mode 0, SPI
                            0x15c 0x10  // SPI0_SCLK Mode 0, SPI
                            >;
            };
        };
    };

    fragment@1 {
        target = <&spi0>;
        __overlay__ {  
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size.cells = <0>;

            compatible = "bone-pinmux-helper";
            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&spi_slave>;
            status = "okay";            
        };
    };
};
```

Then I compile my dts file and copy the compiled file to /lib/Firmware.

```
dtc -O dtb -o SPI_SLAVE_PINMUX-00A0.dtbo -b O -@ SPI_SLAVE_PINMUX-00A0.dts
```

After that I install the driver:

```
echo SPI_SLAVE_PINMUX > /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
```

The overlay is loaded:

```
root@beaglebone:~# cat /sys/devices/platform/bone_capemgr/slots
 0: PF----  -1
 1: PF----  -1
 2: PF----  -1
 3: PF----  -1
 4: P-O-L-   0 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,cape-universaln
 7: P-O-L-   1 Override Board Name,00A0,Override Manuf,SPI_SLAVE_PINMUX
```

Now the problem: if I execute the following command:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/pinctrl/44e10800.pinmux/Pins
```

I can see that nothing has changed.

```
pin 84 (44e10950.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
pin 85 (44e10954.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
pin 86 (44e10958.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
pin 87 (44e1095c.0) 00000037 pinctrl-single
```

And I am wondering how this device tree fits to my device driver (char device driver, with access to MCSPI Memory to manipulate registers), but that's a different story... ;)

I would be very grateful, if someone could help me through ...

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Today I tried an older Image (Debian Wheezy 2015-11-12, Kernel version 3.8.13-bone79) and surprisingly it worked! It seems that the recent Kernel (4.1.15-ti-rt-r43) has problems with this, but I unfortunately do not know why... Nevertheless I am happy to get it working. So: Debian Wheezy 2015-11-12, Kernel version 3.8.13-bone79 and the tutorial: http://www.valvers.com/embedded-linux/beaglebone-black/step04-gpio/ shoud do the trick.